# Find indices where there is an None type and filter

Tags: python, list, filter

I have two lists of strings, some of which have 'None' type. I want to filter based off the indices from both the lists. I have done this in MATLAB, and below is a pseudo code.

```
i1 = list1(list1 is not None) #Expecting a boolean list
i2 = list2(list2 is not None) #Expecting a boolean list


list1_filtered = list1[i1]
list2_filtered = list2[i2]
```

How do I do this? (Edit: I want items that are 'not None')

Comment: Are you just looking to drop None values from both of the lists? if so `[a for a in list1 if a != None]` should work.

Comment: @MasonCaiby checks for None should use ```is```

Comment: @TomLubenow good point, I assumed he wanted the non-None values. I've just never wanted the Nones from my list. @SEU if you want the indicies of None values you could do something like `[i for i in range(len(list1)) if list1[i] is None]` if you want a boolean list of which indicies are None or not `[a is None for a in list1]`

Comment: Yeah, after re-reading the question I can't actually tell if OP wants the ```None```s or the ```not None```s. He may have been looking for the ```is None``` so he knows what indices to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `filter()`

```py
list1_filtered = filter(lambda x: x is not None, list1)
list2_filtered = filter(lambda x: x is not None, list2)
```

You might be surprised at how rarely you have to use indices in Python.

Comment: Or if indexes are really needed: `filter(lambda x: x[1] is not None, enumerate(list1))`

Comment: Clever. I think, though, that that will give you a list of tuples of (index, True), so if you just want the indices you'll have to do a second pass through the list or some zip-slice with an asterisk thrown in there somewhere.

Comment: Oh, yes. I see two possible approaches. The first one is `filter(lambda idx: list1[idx] is not None, range(len(list1)))`. And the second one is `map(lambda y: y[0], filter(lambda x: x[1] is not None, enumerate(list1)))` -- if I am right, both `map` and `filter` returns an iterator (so it is lazy calculations) and only one pass will be done.

Comment: Those both look right to me, I'd personally take the former as it looks simpler. I wouldn't have thought of having the lambda check the list via index.